# URL rewrite for mapped cloudservice URL

Tags: model-view-controller, url-rewriting, dns, routes, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure cloudservice which has a URL like http://mysite.cloudapp.net. I have mapped this URL with my domain like http://stagingenv/folder1/folder2 or http://www.proddomain.com/folder1/folder2.

By this I am able to use the Azure cloud hosting and use the domain name, but the issue is when I browse all my content like CSS/JS/Images/Routes that are relative to my cloud service, I see that they are broken and wont worker till I prepend every URL with "/folder1/folder2/". Can anyone please help what will be the best solution to fix this?

For now, I have this subpath of "/folder1/folder2/" configured in my web config and append it to every content/route i have for my site which I think is **not a very good solution**.

E.g. 
Azure Cloud Service - http://mysite.cloudapp.net
DNS Mapping - http://www.proddomain.com/folder1/folder2
Issue is to include folder1/folder2 for every request to load all JS/CSS/Images/Routes/etc

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please be more specific on what you want to achieve? In MVC, static content is served with the same path you see in your project. If you post an example of what the original URL and the desired URL are, then we'll be able to help you.

Comment: @gbellman I have done a DNS mapping for my azure cloud service and the mapped URL will be www.mysite.com/folder1/folder2. cloud service will remain as is but will be served using above URL. MVC bundling takes relative URLs and when i have mapped with the above URL the relative URL will take www.mysite.com and not folder1/folder2 and so the content like scripts css images doesnt load. My question is how can i include folder1/folder2 to load them. Again please consider that my routes will also not work coz of this folder structure..